# How to make Ubuntu start with a fixed resolution output when no monitor is connected

Tags: ubuntu, video, monitor

The following hardware setup:
- a Ubuntu 14.04.4 Computer
- a Panasonic projector connected to the computer
- a shared desktop enabled to remote service the computer

The problem: Ubuntu does not start up with a correct video setting when no monitor is connected. This is the case when the projector is on standby while the computer boots. The desktop is not even functional available (freezes) when logging on to the computer via shared desktop. Also the projector does not get the right signal when switched on in this state later.

Is there a way to force Ubuntu to use the last or a given monitor setup of the good case which will be used or forced as a default when there is no monitor connected on startup?

The possible solution I found was to use a dummy video device and manually set up a xorg.conf which I already tried to set it up but seems to be quite complicated to make the real and the dummy output work as a cloned output setup alongside. Here is what I have got so far, any help on this is highly appreciated when there is no simpler solution:

```
Section "Device" 
Identifier "Configured Video Device" 
Driver "dummy" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
Identifier "Configured Monitor" 
Option "DPMS" 
EndSection 

#Section "Device" 
# Identifier "GeForce GTX 680" 
# Driver "dummy" 
#EndSection 

#Section "Monitor" 
# Identifier "Configured Projector" 
# Option "DPMS" 
#EndSection 

Section "Screen" 
Identifier "Default Screen" 
Monitor "Configured Monitor" 
Device "Configured Video Device" 
DefaultDepth 24 
SubSection "Display" 
Depth 24 
Virtual 1280 800 
EndSubSection 
# SubSection "Display" 
# Depth 24 
# Modes 1280 800 
# EndSubSection 
EndSection
```

The out commented lines did stall the thing and the config as is works to get the dummy started but without the real video output (there only was a Ubuntu logo but no desktop).

I place this file named xorg.conf to:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```